# PowerShell - Unable to find web elements using Invoke-WebRequest

Tags: powershell, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape data from webpage http://www.theedge.co.nz/home.html using PowerShell.  I want to extract the song title and artist text from this page.

[image]

I can see the elements are there when I inspect them.

[image]

But when I run the following script I'm unable to capture the information:

```
$Web = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://www.theedge.co.nz/home.html"
$web.AllElements | Where {$_.tagname -eq "p"} | select innertext
```

I'm not sure if my code is wrong or that it is a limitation and just not possible to achieve using PowerShell.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: WARNING: NOT AN EXPERT. I see a pseduo class before that class on chrome at least. When I scrape the page with iwr I do not see that text or class. I wonder if the site is designed so you can not do this. In other words when I search for the class c-NavPlayer-Copy in the response I cannot find it. I can find the parent li class but nothing past that.

Comment: That is loaded dynamically by JavaScript from another URI, a REST endpoint by the loos of it which returns JSON; try `Invoke-RestMethod 'http://radio-api.mediaworks.nz/radio-api/v3/station/theedge/network/web' | % nowplaying`

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Nice find. Assuming the answer is small enough how did you find that out?

Comment: @Matt - Given the data wasn't in the Invoke-WebRequest output, I was already thinking it might be that (or in an iFrame-equivalent); I loaded the page in Chrome and noticed the Now Playing section load later than the rest of the page; it makes sense that it's dynamic so it can update as the song changes, so I pressed F12 to open Chrome dev tools, switched to the 'network' tab, cleared it, reloaded the page, clicked the button to filter the requests to 'XHR' only, and there it is, only one URI - click on it, see the preview is the data for NowPlaying, open in new tab - it's JSON.

Comment: Thanks @TessellatingHeckler - Perfect!

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler sorry trying to replicate the same scenario for a different website - http://www.theheat.co.nz/ but following your suggestions in your last comment i'm unable to capture the same details from this site, are you help again please

Comment: @VernonW looks like that one pulls the information in over a WebSocket, which is a completely different technology from HTTP requests. There is websocket support in .Net from Windows 8 onwards, but it's going to be a case of googling 'powershell websocket' and exploring from there, I think.

Comment: Always use fiddler to understand what a website is doing. UI rendering is not a trustworthy source to match with what really happened on the browser.